# How do I keep my device safe from USB Rubber Ducky?

Tags: usb, hid, usb-hid

I'm looking for an answer about OS config or security tools, not like "do not plug it in your computer".

So, There's any way to keep my device (PC, smartphone, tablet...) safe from USB Rubber Ducky?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can disable your USB ports, (which is sort of the same as 'do not plug it in'). Other than that you either have the default helpful state where you do not have to approve device (such as a keyboard) but where you are vulnerable, or you secure things and 99% of the users will not use it because unsafe but easy is more convenient.

Comment: Group policy can ignore all devices that are not implicitly allowed